# Finding a rectangle or square on boundary of convex figure

Tags: geometry

Consider a given (arbitrary) convex polygon.
a.) Does there exist a rectangle with all four vertices on the boundary?
b.) Does there exist a square with all four vertices on the boundary?
Does the same hold if convex polygon is instead replaced with convex figure?

Comment: This looks like a intermediate value theorem problem.

Comment: Can you please expand on that?

Comment: The idea should be something like moving two points $P,Q$ on the polygon and draw perpendicular lines to $PQ$ from $P$ and $Q$, intersecting the polygon at $R,S$. At some point $PR>QS$ and at some point $PR<QS$ so by intermediate value theorem there must be at some point $PR=QS$ forcing a rectangle to exist. However coming up with the right way to move $P,Q$ and choosing the initial position of them is not  easy.

Comment: Part (a) of the first question can be done as follows. Find a particular side of the polygon such that there is an opposite vertex directly above it (in particular if that side is oriented to be horizontal the vertex is vertically above it). Then take this vertex and take a point epsilon below it and draw a line parallel to the side and see where it intersects the polygon. Taking these two points and the two points directly "below" them on the opposite side we have a rectangle. This approach however truly relies on having a "side" so it will not work for the last two questions.